# Skip couple of lines while reading a csv file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a CSV file that has some header information before the actual CSV starts.

I want to **skip all the rows from 1-19** and then start reading my CSV from row **20th (highlighted in yellow)** then **skip two rows 21st and 22nd AND last row 30th**  and then start processing the rest of the file.

Please find attached snapshot.

[image]

The code I am trying to run is:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\xyz\\Downloads\\Spark\\avltest.csv",error_bad_lines=False)
temp = df.loc[20:]    
print(temp)
```

How can I achieve my use-case? I want to parse/read-only the rows I have mentioned above through Python script.

Edit : I am getting the following error with the solution provided:

[image]

Comment: include the argument `skiprows = list(range(19))+[20,21,29]`

Answer (score 1):

`pandas.read_csv`'s `skiprows` can take a callable:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

# Sample data: need to skip from 0 to 4 and then 6
text = """garbage 1
garbage 2
garbage 3
garbage 4

indexTITLE a b c
garbage LONG LONG LONG
0 1 2 3
"""
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(text), sep='\s+', skiprows = lambda x: x in [0,1,2,3,4,6])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   indexTITLE  a  b  c
0           0  1  2  3
```

So all you need to do is make a list of index of rows you want to skip.

Comment: I am getting the following error:

File "C:\Users\shraddhasrivastav\PycharmProjects\AVL\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 685, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "C:\Users\shraddhasrivastav\PycharmProjects\AVL\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 457, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(fp_or_buf, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\shraddhasrivastav\PycharmProjects\AVL\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 895, in __init__
    self._make_engine(self.engine)

Comment: Can you try without `sep='\s+'` part?

Comment: Tried same error: 

File "C:\Users\shraddhasrivastav\PycharmProjects\AVL\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1135, in _make_engine
    self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
  File "C:\Users\shraddhasrivastav\PycharmProjects\AVL\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1917, in __init__
    self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 545, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__
pandas.errors.EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file

Comment: Its saying that you've skipped **all** rows, and thus nothing to parse. Make sure you keep some rows.